# package ‘shinyapps’ is not available (for R version 3.3.0)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I've recently upgraded to R 3.3.0 and am trying to deploy a Shiny app via `deployApp()`, which comes from the package `shinyapps`.  However, I ran into this issue:

```
> install.packages("shinyapps")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘shinyapps’ is not available (for R version 3.3.0)
```

Downgrading my R version is not an option because it interferes with latest versions of other packages that my Shiny app depends on.

Is there some other way that I can deploy my app to the Shiny servers using `deployApp()`?  Here's a sample recipe: http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/deploying-apps-with-shinyapps-io/.

Comment: have you tried: `install.packages("shinyapps", type="source")` or `devtools::install_github("rstudio/shinyapps")`?

Comment: Try install_github like @VincentBonhomme suggested. It's probably not in the main CRAN yet.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, should I delete my question now or keep it up?  I +1'ed both of your comments...

Comment: @warship: I suggest you keep it up. It helped me!

Comment: The shinyapps R package is deprecated and has been replaced by the rsconnect package. You can use the below to install the same

Comment: devtools::install_github("rstudio/rsconnect")

Answer (score 0):

You must create your account at https://www.shinyapps.io/. After that, in the Dashboard, you will need these three steps to publish your app:

Step1: INSTALL RSCONNECT

```
install.packages('rsconnect')
```

Step2: AUTHORIZE ACCOUNT

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='username',
          token='<YOUR TOKEN>',
          secret='<SECRET>')
```

Step3: DEPLOY

```
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp('path/to/your/app')
```